# Is there a standard way of checking for a named executable with autoconf

Tags: autoconf

I have a project using autoconf. On my build server it fails to build because the makefile refers to `makeinfo`, which is not currently installed on the build server, but the error is not caught until compile time. I'd like to ensure that the problem is caught at configure time and gives a sensible error message.

I can't find a standard macro that will check for the existence of an executable named 'makeinfo'. I could write my own, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there something generic that I'm missing? Or even a specific check for makeinfo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about **AC_CHECK_PROG** or **AC_PATH_PROG**?

http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Generic-Programs.html#Generic-Programs